# Is it ok to use AWS RDS with Azure VM's

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

We have mysql databases which we want to host on AWS RDS and want to Azure VM's both of them co-located , is it OK to do something like this ?

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Since AWS and Azure are two separate services, how can they be co-located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider this:

1. You will incur unnecessary data transfer costs between them
2. The latency might cause a bottleneck
3. You will need to open up the Amazon RDS with a public endpoint, increasing security risks

Answer (score 2):

Yes its OK, yes it will work, no its probably not the best architecture because of the latency between the two.

I'd either move the DB to azure, or the VM's to AWS...either option will probably be more satisfactory to you.